# Absence of Anti-CSRF Tokens & Server Leaks Information via "X-Powered-By" : How do I set it?

Tags: php, apache, httpresponse, csrf-token

I am currently using Apache server for Wamp application for my project. While doing a security scanning, the report came out with 2 errors:

1. Server Leaks Information via "X-Powered-By" HTTP Response Header Field(s)
2. Absence of Anti-CSRF Tokens

What do I need to do to solve these? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a help here you can implement csrf tokens:
https://code-boxx.com/simple-csrf-token-php/

You can read more about what is csrf token and why it's useful here:https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf/tokens

> A CSRF token is a unique, secret, unpredictable value that is
> generated by the server-side application and transmitted to the client
> in such a way that it is included in a subsequent HTTP request made by
> the client. When the later request is made, the server-side
> application validates that the request includes the expected token and
> rejects the request if the token is missing or invalid.
>
> CSRF tokens can prevent CSRF attacks by making it impossible for an
> attacker to construct a fully valid HTTP request suitable for feeding
> to a victim user. Since the attacker cannot determine or predict the
> value of a user's CSRF token, they cannot construct a request with all
> the parameters that are necessary for the application to honor the
> request.

And for removing `X-Powered-By` you can set `expose_php = off` in your `php.ini` file

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll give it a read. :)

Comment: Your welcome. And if it helped, check it as correct answer.

Comment: Hi, if my form is in a html file, do I have to change the file to php to do it?

Comment: HI. Yes, if you want to use any php code in your file it should have .php extension. And also you can change web server setting but it is not recommended.